# Restricting users abilities on Linux (ratio / bandwitdh)

Tags: linux, permissions

is it possible to easily set some users permissions on Linux? (actually my distro is Ubuntu server 9.04)

I mean:

- give them a maximum amount of space for their home folder
- restrincting the bandwidth that they can use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limiting bandwidth on a per-user basis can be done [with a bit of elbow grease](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/iptables-and-tc-for-limiting-bandwidth-per-linux-user-744365/).

Comment: +1 Oh that is cool.  Since it is cooler then just linking to quota for nth time, feel free to add my quota part to your answer so yours s definitive.

Answer (score 0):

For the quota porition you just want to install `quota`, `sudo apt-get install quota`.  Bandwidth, I am not sure...